# Why does Designer Code for Color convert to byte then to integer?

Tags: vb.net, forms, performance, windows-forms-designer

vb.net's form designer uses this code to set a button's color:

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(64, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(0, Byte), Integer))
```

Why doesn't it just do

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0))
```

?
As far as I can tell, it slows it down for no real reason. I assume it's to prevent some crash, but I don't know how it would.

Comment: it is assuring that the values are legal.  RGB values must be 0-255 which happens to be the range for a Byte.  You arent supposed to have to edit/fix the designer code, so it is important that it be as crash proof as possible,

Comment: But this is only the values from the form designer, and isn't that limited to 255 just from the gui?

Comment: so a related question is why `FromArgb` accepts `int` rather than `Byte`...

Comment: Yes, but the designer code **is** able to be opened and edited by you.  In case someone does change something, they dont want the form creation to fail.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I assume most developers are likely to store the RGB values as Integers even though they are 0-255. If FromArgb only accepted Byte, everyone would have to convert their Integers to Bytes before calling the method.

Comment: @Blackwood True.  Just [poking around](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,42f1c32b4b24f27f) in [the code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,e0eabd6da4f39607,references) should anyone else be interested...

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a reason for this.  The RGB values need to be in the range of 0-255, so casting them to Byte assures that to be the case, forcing an illegal value such as `260` to `4`.

Since the Designer *can* be opened and changed, it is important that it not crash when creating the form in the IDE.  Casting the values helps in cases where someone 'tweaks' a value directly in the designer code.